# MySQL to return multiple differences between many rows

Tags: mysql

I have following problem that I would need to return multiple differences on values in one table based on specifications given in other two tables. I'm pretty certain that this can be accomplished with some inner joins in right place. The greatest problem that I have is the fact that one there might also be more than two values that need to be compared and the results should be always returned in one row.

The differences that should be returned are calculated from values in Table C and the specifications of what should be compared are given in Table A.

Below I have made an example of the situation as it's easier to show the situation and an example return row. I have tried many tricks but without success so your help would be greatly appreciated.

The database uses MySQL.

Thanks in advance!

Table A:

```
|  identifier  |  type   |   top_id
-------------------------------------
|   aaaa       |   X     |   
|   bbbb       |   Y     |    aaaa
|   cccc       |   Y     |    aaaa
|   dddd       |   Y     |    aaaa
```

Table B:

```
|  identifier  |  is_base
--------------------------
|   bbbb       |   TRUE
|   cccc       |   FALSE
|   dddd       |   FALSE
```

Table C:

```
|  identifier  |  type   | sub_type |  value
----------------------------------------------
|   bbbb       |   A     |    Q     |   100
|   cccc       |   A     |    Q     |   90
|   dddd       |   A     |    Q     |   80
```

Result:

```
|    top_id    |    base    |   diff1_id |  diff1_value  |  diff2_id  |  diff2_value   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    aaaa      |    bbbb    |    cccc    |     10        |   dddd     |     20
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select at.top_id,
       ct.identifier,
       group_concat(concat(cf.identifier,':', ct.value-cf.value)) diffs
from TableA at
join TableB bt on at.identifier = bt.identifier and bt.is_base = 'TRUE'
join TableC ct on bt.identifier = ct.identifier 
join TableA af on at.top_id = af.top_id
join TableB bf on af.identifier = bf.identifier and bf.is_base = 'FALSE'
join TableC cf on bf.identifier = cf.identifier 
group by ct.identifier
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47ce4/6).